# Selecting data in parenthesis

Tags: python, pandas, slice, parentheses

I have a list of movies in a csv file, 100rows x 1column that looks like this:

```
1. Mulholland Drive (David Lynch, 2001)
```

I'm trying to get rid of the number in the front, put the title, director, and year in each column. I did:

```
rank = pd.read_csv("/Users/...csv", header = 0) 
rank.columns = ['1']
rank['1'] = rank['1'].str[3:]
```

to get rid of all the numbers in the front, so next, I wanted to separate what's in the parenthesis by:

```
rank = rank[rank.find("(")+1:rank.find(")")]
```

but am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Could update your entire code?

Comment: May you show an example of expected register to guide us to a solution?

Comment: you should check the regex capture method below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're always definitely in that format, for instance - mocking up a file with just the given example (not that if you've got brackets or commas etc... etc... that don't match the format - this'll break):

```
rank = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv', header=None, names=['film'])
df = rank.film.str.extract('(?:\d+\.\s+)(.*?)\((.*?),\s+(\d+)\)', expand=True)
```

Which'll give you:

```
                   0            1     2
0  Mulholland Drive   David Lynch  2001
```

Comment: I'd take it one step further and imbed column names in regex.  `regex = r'(?:\d+\.\s+)(?P<Title>.*?)\((?P<Director>.*?),\s+(?P<Year>\d+)\)'` Then 
`rank.film.str.extract(regex, expand=True)`

Comment: @piRSquared nice idea :)